# Difference between ['a']*10 and ['a' for i in range(10)] in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and noticed something. My run time was significantly lower when i used ['a' for i in range(10)] compared to ['a']*10. Can someone please explain why this happens?

Comment: Well, `['a']*10` should be faster. In this case, there is no difference, but in general, it is very different. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly

Comment: Show us your benchmark code.  Several of us are dubious of your results.

Comment: it was used in a LC question. the run time was slower if i declared the array using for loop.

Answer (score 0):

`['a' for i in range(10)]` executes the following in Python:

- Create a range
- Iterate the range, and for each iteration:

  - Assign the iterated value to a locally defined variable `i`
  - Produce `'a'`
- Collect the produced strings into a list

`['a']*10` executes the following:

- Produce `'a'` (once)
- Collect the given number of occurrences of `'a'` into a list

This is simplified, but it is clear that the second version:

- has no need of explicitly creating a (range) iterator;
- has no need of defining a local variable `i`;
- has no iteration that is explicitly running as Python code; the iteration only happens in lower-level, compiled code.